# Oracle12: calling a procedure inside a Package

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, dbms-job

I have a DBMS_JOB job declares as follows

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
job_name => 'GET_ENAGAS_INVOICES_JOB',
job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
job_action => 'BEGIN LOPES.GET_ENAGAS_INVOICES; END;',
repeat_interval =>'FREQ=MINUTELY; INTERVAL=5; BYHOUR=9,22; BYDAY=TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN', 
enabled => TRUE,
comments => 'GET_ENAGAS_INVOICES');
END;
/
```

I moved this procedure inside a package and I want to know if it is still possible to run the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use `SCHEMA_NAME.PACKAGE_NAME.PROCEDURE_NAME`:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name => 'GET_ENAGAS_INVOICES_JOB',
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => 'BEGIN LOPES.PACKAGE_NAME.GET_ENAGAS_INVOICES; END;',
    repeat_interval =>'FREQ=MINUTELY; INTERVAL=5; BYHOUR=9,22; BYDAY=TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN', 
    enabled => TRUE,
    comments => 'GET_ENAGAS_INVOICES'
  );
END;
/
```